# How to scope a TraceWriter object in Azure App Functions so that it's available to all methods

Tags: function, azure, scope

I have an Azure APP function that - aside from the main method that is called via HTTP trigger - has some helper methods inside it.

I want to be able to log events in all of those methods. There is a TraceWriter object that is passed into the main entry method when invoked. Currently, I pass the TraceWriter object as a parameter into every helper method that is called so I can use it to log information.

Is there any reason that it isn't more suitable to just have it available as a public static object at the top of the class, and then be able to call it in every method without having to pass it into each method individually? e.g.

Instead of having to have each method as

```
public static fooMethod(string input, TraceWriter log)
```

and

```
public static fooMethod2(string moreinput, TraceWriter log)
```

Simply make the object available to all methods via:

```
public static class GetADUser
{
    public static TraceWriter myLog; <-- 

    [FunctionName("GetADUser")]
    public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"--> Beginning function execution");

        string name = req.Query["name"];
        log.Info($"Querying {name}");

        var f = AzureADExtensions.GetAllUsers(null, name);
        dynamic azureADUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(f.Result);

        var userCount = azureADUser.value.Count;

        return azureADUser = (userCount == 1)
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(azureADUser.ToString())
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Nothing found");


    }
}
```

So that within our other methods it is now

```
public static fooMethod(string input)
{
    GetADUser.myLog.Info("");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people believe in injecting ILoggers or the like into every class that needs to log. I personally don’t subscribe to that belief, as I see logging as a cross cutting concern, and not so much a dependency. I personally prefer to use System.Diagnostics.Trace static methods and rely on whatever logging implementation I’m using to add appropriate TraceListeners. With regard to an Azure Function which forces you to rely on an instance of TraceWriter, this can be accomplished using an AsyncLocal (basically a thread static value that is async compatible)

Here is a simplistic version that just directly exposes the TraceWriter

```
    public class CurrentTraceWriter
    {
        public static readonly AsyncLocal<TraceWriter> Current = new AsyncLocal<TraceWriter>();
    }
```

You can set Current.Value to the TraceWriter instance you get passed to your function.

And here is an example of how you might do the same for NLog (this is what we do)

```
/// <summary>
///     Adds contextual function invocation information as scoped properties to NLog and redirects all NLog messages to the
///     current function runtime's ILogger instance.
/// </summary>
public class LoggingFilter : IFunctionInvocationFilter
{
    private const string ScopePropertyName = "LogFilterScope";

    private static readonly AsyncLocal<ILogger> CurrentFunctionLogger =
        new AsyncLocal<ILogger>();

    static LoggingFilter()
    {
        if (!Trace.Listeners.OfType<NLogTraceListener>().Any()) Trace.Listeners.Add(new NLogTraceListener());

        Target.Register<FunctionLoggerTarget>(nameof(FunctionLoggerTarget));
        LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = true;
        LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
    }

    public Task OnExecutingAsync(FunctionExecutingContext executingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var scopes = new[]
        {
            MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped(nameof(executingContext.FunctionInstanceId),
                executingContext.FunctionInstanceId),
            MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped(nameof(executingContext.FunctionName),
                executingContext.FunctionName)
        };

        CurrentFunctionLogger.Value = executingContext.Logger;

        executingContext.Properties[ScopePropertyName] = scopes;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task OnExecutedAsync(FunctionExecutedContext executedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!executedContext.Properties.TryGetValue(ScopePropertyName, out var scopes) || !(scopes is IDisposable[]))
            LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Warn(
                $"No existing scoped properties were found for invocation {executedContext.FunctionInstanceId} of function ${executedContext.FunctionName}. This most likely indicates a problem in the function invocation pipeline");

        foreach (var scope in (IDisposable[]) scopes) scope.Dispose();
        CurrentFunctionLogger.Value = null;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task OnExceptionAsync(FunctionExceptionContext exceptionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Error(exceptionContext.Exception);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Forwards NLog messages to current function invocation Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger
    /// </summary>
    public class FunctionLoggerTarget : TargetWithLayout
    {
        protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            CurrentFunctionLogger.Value?.Log((LogLevel) logEvent.Level.Ordinal,
                default(EventId), logEvent, logEvent.Exception, (s, e) => Layout.Render(logEvent));

            base.Write(logEvent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Can I ask what is the benefit of using AsyncLocal<> in your example, over the use of just static TraceWriter in my example?

Comment: All executions of the function will share the same static TraceWriter. You’ll run into concurrency issues and you’ll lose context - each TraceWriter instance is bound to the specific invocation of the function to which it’s passed. Meaning if two invocations are running at the same time (A and B), log messages from A may appear to be associated with invocation B and vice verse.

Comment: Got it - thanks, makes sense. Really appreciate the info Jeff.